# Calculate EMVA1288 temporal dark noise

Tags: image-sensor, ccd

Say I have a dark current plot (image mean over shutter time) with an offset (y-intercept) of 4100 and system gain K = 4.23, is the following calculation correct?

Variance of dark signal = sqrt(4100) = 64.

Temporal dark noise = sqrt(64)/K = 1.89 electrons.

Comment: Perhaps provide a link to the standard, the formulae that you are referring to and/or the  page number to make the effort of those helping you easier.  Most people here will not have even heard of this standard.  On the other hand I would encourage you to conform to this standard as much as possible, it is well written and provides a good framework for the objective comparison of image sensors from one manufacturer to another.

Comment: I knew that you would be the one to answer! :) I think I will withdraw and delete this question after giving this some more thought. I think I made a wrong assumption. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's a valid question and worthwhile, you need to give people more background.  Your assumption of variance being = sqrt(mean) is not correct you need to compare the variance AGAINST the sqrt(mean) to get the parameters you want.  Like PTC for the dark (PTC = Photon transfer curve)

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to see that other people are working with EMVA1288 as i'm one of the authors and test equipment manufacturer.

Your calculation is incorrect. The total noise is not the dark temporal noise, you need to get rid of the fixed pattern noise.

In EMVA1288, we do this by accumulating images in large quantities to separate the fixed noise and the temporal noise. This is quite well explained in the standard. If you do not exactly follow the procedures in the standard then you will not be compliant. There are more details to come about this compliance in future versions of the standard.

Comment: If you had a link to the current standard I could add it into the question if you like, it'd make it clearer what the standard is about.